# Why is the graph of $\frac{2x-6}{x^2}$ over the $x$ axis, if the numerator isn't negative?

Tags: graphing-functions

The graph of $\frac{2x-6}{x^2}$ is reflected over the $y$-axis, but I'm failing to see where a negative sign would affect the $y$ value.

Answer (score 0):

$2x-6<0$ if $x<3$,

Hence $y=\frac{2x-6}{x^2}<0$ if $x<3$ and $x\neq 0$.

Remark: the function is not an even function.